# pdfpages package and \fbox collision

Tags: boxes, framed, pdfpages

There seems to be a collision between `pdfpages` package and other packages that use `\fboxrule`, `\fboxsep`, etc.

Here is an example:
Using `frame=true`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\fancypage{\fbox}{}
\includepdf[pages=-,
            frame=true,
            scale=0.75]
            {dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and using `frame=false`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\fancypage{\fbox}{}
\includepdf[pages=-,
            frame=false,
            scale=0.75]
            {dummy.pdf}
\end{document}
```

How can I overcome this problem and use `\fbox` and `pdfpages` with `frame=false`?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't post images until you get 10 rep points. Until then simply remove the `!` in front of the image code to turn them into a link instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\fancypage{\fboxrule=1pt\fbox}{}`